# Is there anyway to take a screenshot with maximum PPI?

Tags: python, python-tesseract, python-mss

I'm trying to take screenshot on my Mac and for I need to pass the screenshot to pytesseract, I'd like to know if there is anyway for grabbing a region of the screen at the maximum PPI.
I noticed that it's always 72 DPI, is there anyway to take it at 100DPI for example?

I have a MacBook Pro 15 inch 2017, so almost 220 PPI.

Thanks in advance